# PHP foreach won't work

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php
 $xml=simplexml_load_file("<dict>
 <key>ChannelID</key>
 <string>example</string>
 <key>ChannelDVRs</key>
 <array>
 <dict>
 <key>id</key>
 <string>LIVE</string>
 <key>name</key>
 <string>example1111</string>
 <key>description</key>
 <string>Live</string>
 <key>logoUrl</key>
 <string>http://www.example.com/logos/190x110/298.jpg</string>
 <key>logoUrlSD</key>
 <string>http://www.example.com/logos/190x110/298.jpg</string>
 <key>isVOD</key>
 <string>false</string>
 <key>StreamURL</key>
 <string>exampleessssssssssss test</string>
 </dict>
 </array>
 </dict>") 
 or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach ($xml->string as $output) {
echo "$output <br>";
}?>
```

If there is some way to get the last string which says `exampleessssssssssss test` I don't need to use foreach. THANK for any help ;)

Comment: Look at `load_file`... or http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: It's was url link there, as a result I'm  getting only <string>example</string>

Comment: Oh, so this isn't your actual code. Rather than `What am I doing wrong here?` you should describe what currently happens. The question is really `I don't need to use foreach?` which has been answered below with `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the XML string properly, then fetch the right element.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string(
    "<dict>
        <key>ChannelID</key>
        <string>example</string>
        <key>ChannelDVRs</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>id</key>
                <string>LIVE</string>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>example1111</string>
                <key>description</key>
                <string>Live</string>
                <key>logoUrl</key>
                <string>http://www.example.com/logos/190x110/298.jpg</string>
                <key>logoUrlSD</key>
                <string>http://www.example.com/logos/190x110/298.jpg</string>
                <key>isVOD</key>
                <string>false</string>
                <key>StreamURL</key>
                <string>exampleessssssssssss test</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>") 
 or die("Error: Cannot create object");

echo end($xml->array->dict->string); //output exampleessssssssssss test
```

`$xml->array->dict->string` is an array, so the `end()` function will get the last element, as you seems to want.

Comment: and now how can I use str_replace function when i echoing?

Comment: I'll do that :) It says :You can accept an answer in 4 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative, which doesn't rely on the content being in any order other than being the element following `<key>StreamURL</key>`.  This ensures that if there are future changes, the code doesn't stop working.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string("<dict>
 <key>ChannelID</key>
 <string>example</string>
 <key>ChannelDVRs</key>
 <array>
 <dict>
 <key>id</key>
 <string>LIVE</string>
 <key>name</key>
 <string>example1111</string>
 <key>description</key>
 <string>Live</string>
 <key>logoUrl</key>
 <string>http://www.example.com/logos/190x110/298.jpg</string>
 <key>logoUrlSD</key>
 <string>http://www.example.com/logos/190x110/298.jpg</string>
 <key>isVOD</key>
 <string>false</string>
 <key>StreamURL</key>
 <string>exampleessssssssssss test</string>
 </dict>
 </array>
 </dict>")
 or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$text = $xml->xpath('//key[text()="StreamURL"]/following-sibling::string/text()');
echo (string)$text[0];
```

Using XPath allows you to search based on an elements content and then this picks up the following `<string>` element.  As `xpath()` returns a list of matching nodes, use `[0]` to get the first item.

Answer (score 0):

altering @Felippe Duarte code to echo with str_replace use the below code

```
$str =  end($xml->array->dict->string);
$edited_str = str_replace("exampleessssssssssss","examples",$str);
echo $edited_str;
```